# Swift package with submodules like in CocoaPods

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to translate a Pod I'm creating to Swift Package Manager (SPM), but don't know how to translate the `subspec` feature from CocoaPods to SPM. I know SPM provides multiple targets, but afaik this isn't the same as the `subspec` feature.

Let's say I have the following podspec:

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name = 'Example'
    ...

    # main spec
    s.subspec 'Main' do |ss|
        ss.source_files = 'Source/Main/**/*.swift'
        ss.pod_target_xcconfig = {
            'SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS[config=Debug]' => 'DEBUG'
        }

        # dependencies
        ss.dependency 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'
    end

    # coredata
    s.subspec 'CoreData' do |ss|
        ss.source_files = 'Source/CoreData/**/*.swift'
        ss.pod_target_xcconfig = {
            'SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS[config=Debug]' => 'EXAMPLE_WITH_COREDATA',
            'SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS' => 'EXAMPLE_WITH_COREDATA'
        }

        # dependencies
        ss.dependency 'Example/Core'
        ss.dependency 'MagicalRecord', '> 2.3'
    end
end
```

If the developer depends on the `CoreData` subspec, it will automatically include the `Main` subspec, but also set some flags for the pod. This way, the `Main` pod knows that extra functionality is available, and integrates it. Quick example of code from the `Main` subspec:

```swift
func someFunction() {
    // ... some code ...

    #if EXAMPLE_WITH_COREDATA
        callExtraCoreDataRelatedMethod()
    #endif

    // ... some code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something which is supported yet by the Swift package manager (customizing the behavior of a target based on how it is used by other targets).

If you have a package which you want to do this, for now you have to do it via some kind of runtime registration where the `CoreData` module would register the fact with the `Main` module that it needed this other bit of behavior.

Comment: Hmm, alright. Behaviour aside (of the module), what about the dependencies? How can I define multiple modules in my package, and let a user only include the modules they want? The reference documentation of SPM describes multiple targets, but not how to depend on one of those targets.

Comment: This isn't something implemented yet, although we are aware of the need for it and are actively working on figuring out how it should look.

Comment: Is there an issue in the bug tracker, or a mailing list thread I can follow for this?

Comment: Thx! There's also a proposal here: https://github.com/aciidb0mb3r/swift-evolution/blob/swiftpm-module-access-control/proposals/xxxx-swiftpm-target-access-control.md